# Difference between MemoryPool<T> and ArrayPool<T>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, memory-management

What is the difference between [MemoryPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.memorypool-1?view=netcore-3.1) and [ArrayPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=netcore-3.1) as far as i can tell, they both do the same thing (rent out buffers to reduce garbage collection pressure).

Is there a pool that should be be preferred in read calls to use [`NetworkStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netcore-3.1) or [`WebSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=netcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `ArrayPool<T>` class rents out *Arrays*. In otherwords the `Rent` method returns a `T[]`. The `Shared` property returns a default implementation of an `ArrayPool<T>`, `TlsOverPerCoreLockedStacksArrayPool` which caches the backing arrays in a combination of a `ThreadStatic` array of buckets and local per-core "stacks". It is optimized for the `char` and `byte` cases. The `ConfigurableArrayPool` returned from the `Create` method stores the underlying arrays in an array of `Buckets` (each with its own array of arrays). Additionally you may write your own implementation.

On the other hand, `MemoryPool<T>` is a bit more generic in that it deals ultimately with `Memory<T>` objects. The `Rent` method hands out `IMemoryOwner<T>` implementations, which are responsible for, well, *owning* a `Memory<T>`. Memory Owners can be backed by various sources, arrays being one of them. The `MemoryPool<T>.Shared` singleton is actually an `ArrayMemoryPool<T>` which is backed by, you guessed it, `ArrayPool<T>.Shared`. But memory pools may be backed by different sources, for example by unmanaged memory/memory pointed to by a `SafeHandle`.

Which one to use really depends on your requirements:

- If the API you are using requires a `T[]` or you simply want a no-allocation array, then `ArrayPool<T>` is what you want to use.
- If you are working with `Memory<T>` instances, then you want to use a `MemoryPool<T>`

If you are using an API that can take either, there's not necessarily a benefit to using one pool over the other. The API itself may work better with raw `T[]` than it does with `Memory<T>` (or vice versa), but the API should only care about the memory itself and has no knowledge of the pool from which it came.

Comment: Related: https://endjin.com/blog/2020/09/arraypool-vs-memorypool-minimizing-allocations-ais-dotnet