# Why is MemoryPool slower and allocates more than ArrayPool?

Tags: c#, .net-core, heap-memory

I'm not entirely sure if I have done something wrong in my tests, but from my results MemoryPool is consistently slower and allocates more memory than ArrayPool, since you can convert Array type to Memory anyway, what is the point of using MemoryPool?

```
using System.Buffers;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

BenchmarkRunner.Run<test>();

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class test
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void WithArrayPool()
    {
        ArrayPool<int> pool = ArrayPool<int>.Shared;

        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
        {
            var memory = pool.Rent(2347);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
            {
                memory[i] = i + 1;
            }

            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
            {
                total += memory[i];
            }

            pool.Return(memory);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void WithMemoryPool()
    {
        MemoryPool<int> pool = MemoryPool<int>.Shared;

        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
        {
            var rentedArray = pool.Rent(2347);
            var memory = rentedArray.Memory;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
            {
                memory.Span[i] = i + 1;
            }

            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
            {
                total += memory.Span[i];
            }

            rentedArray.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WithArrayPool | 770.2 us | 2.27 us | 2.01 us | 1 B |
| WithMemoryPool | 1,714.6 us | 0.56 us | 0.50 us | 2,402 B |

My test code with results is above. Is Memory Pool actually just slower in general or is there something I am missing? If MemoryPool is in fact slower, what use case does it have?

Thanks.

Comment: _”MemoryPool<T> is a good choice when your code needs to allocate blocks of memory and you would like to reduce the pressure on the GC by reusing the allocated memory rather than creating new memory blocks each time.”_ - https://www.infoworld.com/article/3596289/how-to-use-arraypool-and-memorypool-in-c.html

Comment: But doesn't an ArrayPool do the same thing just with arrays instead of memory<>?

Comment: MemoryPool allocates the IMemoryOwner instances it returns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About the performance.

The repeated call to `memory.Span[i]` is the culprit.
The source code at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3cfd7a0fa781a2b897e7b592746ba386a7136a23/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Memory.cs#L266) shows that quite some handling occurs behind that property getter.

Instead of repeating that call, store the result of that call in a variable

```
var span = memory.Span;
```

See full code block below.

Now the `Mean` numbers are almost equal.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WithArrayPool | 333.4 us | 2.34 us | 5.15 us | 331.0 us | - | - |
| WithMemoryPool | 368.6 us | 7.08 us | 5.53 us | 366.7 us | 0.4883 | 2,400 B |

---

```
[Benchmark]
public void WithMemoryPool()
{
    MemoryPool<int> pool = MemoryPool<int>.Shared;

    for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
    {
        var rentedArray = pool.Rent(2347);
        var memory = rentedArray.Memory;
        var span = memory.Span; 

        for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
        {
            span[i] = i + 1;
        }

        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < memory.Length; i++)
        {
            total += span[i];
        }

        rentedArray.Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

About the difference in allocated memory.

That's by design.
There's already an very good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856306/difference-between-memorypoolt-and-arraypoolt#:%7E:text=Which%20one%20to%20use%20really,to%20use%20a%20MemoryPool) that explains this.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! But MemoryPool is slower regardless, what is an example scenario where it would be a better choice than ArrayPool?

Comment: It depends on the data you use; from that linked post: `memory pools may be backed by different sources, for example by unmanaged memory/memory pointed to by a SafeHandle`.

Comment: So the type of data the array/memory holds, affects the performance? Does that mean that array/memory pools are each better suited to different data types?